# JS Prevent multiple functions running simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am trying to make a page which redirect users to different pages after 20s using different buttons or elements and I want to prevent multiple timeouts I mean i want to keep 20s interval between redirecting to any site.

```js
function redirect1(){
window.open('https://youtube.com', '_blank')
}

function redirect2(){
window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
}
```

```html
<html>
<p onclick='settimeout(redirect1, 20000)'>Youtube</p>
<p onclick='settimeout(redirect2, 20000)'>Google</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below `timeouts[site] = timeouts[site] ||` makes sure that the button can be clicked only once every 20 seconds

Also, created a single function so as not to have repetitive code

```
const redirect = (() => {
    let timeouts = {};
    return (site, delay) => {
        timeouts[site] = timeouts[site] || setTimeout(() => {
            window.open(site, '_blank');
            timeouts[site] = null;
        }, delay);
    };
})();

<html>
<p onclick="redirect('https://youtube.com', 20000)">Youtube</p>
<p onclick="redirect('https://google.com', 20000)">Google</p>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for helping me but i am very sorry to say that it is not working

Comment: it does work, I tested it - any errors in the console?